# VBA to import multiple CSV files into multiple sheets in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am working to make an automated template that imports multiple csv files into multiple sheets in an excel template that I have created.

So far I have one sheet in the template that has a table named Results and a column named Login ID.  I wrote the following script to automatically create sheets and name them.  My table data starts on row 7.

```
Sub Prepare_Report()
Dim WS As Worksheet

'   Go to the results page
    Sheets("Results Page").Select

'   Create all additional sheets from Login ID field in the results table
    Dim N As Long, I As Long
    N = Range("Results[Login ID]").Rows.Count + 6
    For I = 7 To N
    aName = Worksheets("Results Page").Range("C" & I).Value
    Set WS = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))
    WS.Name = aName
    Next I
```

Each CSV file I have to import is named after one of the Login ID's as well, and they will be located in the same folder as the template I am creating.

the CSV files will need a slight modification to separate the date and time from the first column.

```
'    Columns("A:A").Select
'    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
'    Columns("B:B").Select
'    Selection.Cut Destination:=Columns("A:A")
'    Columns("A:A").Select
'    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
'        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(10, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
'    Columns("A:A").Select
'    Selection.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy;@"
'    Columns("B:B").Select
'    Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
'
```

Any ideas if I am on the right track or how to best solve my CSV import woes would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain further? You want to create a sheet for each csv file you need to import. Is it actually looping through a folder with all .csv files and importing them one by one into each designated sheet that you're uncertain about? If you're not sure how to get started I would suggest looking at `QueryTables.Add` method

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want!

```
Sub CombineTextFiles()

    Dim FilesToOpen
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim wkbAll As Workbook
    Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
    Dim sDelimiter As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    sDelimiter = "|"

    FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
      (FileFilter:="CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", _
      MultiSelect:=True, Title:="CSV Files to Open")

    If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No Files were selected"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If

    x = 1
    Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
    wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy
    Set wkbAll = ActiveWorkbook
    wkbTemp.Close (False)
    wkbAll.Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
      Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
      Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
    x = x + 1

    While x <= UBound(FilesToOpen)
        Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
        With wkbAll
            wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Move After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            .Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
              Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
              TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
              ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
              Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
              Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
              Other:=True, OtherChar:=sDelimiter
        End With
        x = x + 1
    Wend

ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wkbAll = Nothing
    Set wkbTemp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler

End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Only configuration needed it to change False to True for the delimiter you are using in your cvs file.